# Why would you sense peak inductor current at the high-side PMOS transistor rather than at the NMOS?

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

I found this image for peak current mode sensing [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Circuit-diagram-of-the-peak-current-mode-buck-regulator_fig1_276247132).

Is there any reason that you sense the peak inductor current from the MP instead of theMN transistor? I know that ideally both should work but I wonder if there is something relating to practice that sensing MP is prefered.

[image]

This is an example from the [site](https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN028):

[image]

Please tell me what is wrong with my understanding.

Vc is controlled by the load condition. In heavy load condition, Vc increases which in turn increases the duty cycle and inductor current. Conversely for light load condition.

The duty cycle is controlled by the peak inductor current. The peak of the inductor current = peak of rising inductor current = peak of falling inductor current. So as long as you can sense the peak, either peak of rising or falling, both should work.

I agree that there are some problems of low-side sensing because of ringing. Is there another reason that makes low-side sensing not work?

How about if we just sense the inductor current instead of high-side or low-side sensing?

Added question related to simulation:

[image]

[image]

In this simulation you can see that both rising and falling inductor current share the same peak. So would it work with just the falling section of the current?

Answer (score 7):

Because during the cycle when PFET is on, current of PFET and inductor is increasing, and the NFET current is zero.

PFET must be turned off when peak current limit is reached, to terminate the inductor charging cycle.

Comment: But NFET current also goes to peak, just a different direction.

Comment: Yes but current goes via NFET only when PFET is off. How are you going to measure from NFET the current of PFET or inductor during the on cycle, to detect when current limit gets exceeded and it is time to turn PFET off?

Comment: @hana high side sensing allows the current to be detected during the very first cycle. To detect on the low side the controller would have to run the high side for a time it calculates (or guesses!) and then stop and activate the low side to see what the current is. Current mode controllers can have exceptional transient response with this high side sensing method.

Comment: @Bryan sorry  why would it need to guess? Isn't the duty determined by the controller?

Comment: @hana usually, however classical current mode setups interrupt the high part of the duty cycle when the reference current from the error amplifier is reached ( https://www.digikey.ca/en/articles/voltage-and-current-mode-control-for-pwm-signal-generation-in-dc-to-dc-switching-regulators ). Sensing on the low side would require the controller to predict that value, requiring additional sensors (input voltage at a minimum). Without that sensing it would probably have to guess - algoithmically of course, not randomly.

Answer (score 5):

Since the control circuit is shown, the answer can be discovered by following the logic.

If current never reaches peak, then NMOS never turns off, and the output explodes.  Well, maybe not that severe, but at best it reduces to a voltage-mode control (Iramp controlled only, Isense = 0).  And then compensation and startup/fault response sucks.

You could invert the current sense and ramp, and swap the flip-flop inputs, so it goes high starting from when the low side current drops below threshold, until the next oscillator pulse.  But then you lose the peak current sensing feature: it's safer to assume nothing bad will happen during the low phase (it's just circulating load current), less safe to assume the input side always delivers the same slug of charge per pulse.  And if the state ever gets stuck high for multiple clock cycles, the output current is completely unknown.

A low-side-sensing control is possible, and indeed typical, when a more complicated solution is employed: e.g. reconstructing high-side current from the low-side current measured during the previous cycle, give or take measurements of, or assumptions about, Vin, Vout, L, etc.; or when constant-on-time control is used (in which case the ΔI is nominally fixed per cycle).  The latter forces a low-side half-cycle, and thus current sensing opportunity, periodically; even if the rise in current is unexpectedly high during one cycle, it can just stay low for longer until back within nominal range.

Comment: Is that the peak current controlled by the controller so if load current reduces then D reduces --> average inductor current reduce so it always reaches peak?

Comment: @hana To paraphrase a quote by Feynman: "it makes PWM, but that's not why we do it". Inductor current *is* the goal, which directly affects output voltage, therefore the regulator has complete control authority. PWM is more just a side effect here.

Comment: I think I still miss something fundamental that  I couldn't see why. I just edited my post. Can you comment on that?

Comment: I'm not sure where you think the low side current comes from. It's causational. *There is no low-side current until the high side turns off!* It can only ever be sensed once the state changes, but making the state change is exactly what you're sensing for in the first place.

Comment: That makes sense but are you saying that low-side current sensing to control inductor current is not possible? It's confusing as in the comment section  Rohat Kılıç said that both are fine as long as we can sense the peak current.

Comment: Well, I can't speak for his state of knowledge. It seems like he's aware of the causative role, but hasn't come to a complete realization of the overall behavior. That is: the individual points seem correct, but his overall picture is still hazy. At least, that's just my guess from a cursory reading.

Answer (score 5):

When the hi-side MOS (PMOS) is on the current flows from voltage source (input) to inductor, output capacitor, and load. And energy builds up in the inductor's magnetic field during this time. When the charging current reaches to its peak then the PMOS turns off. And, depending on the driver design and conditions, low-side MOS (NMOS) turns on *(it may stay off because its body diode will be in conduction)* and initiates the discharge (reset) cycle of the inductor *(During the reset cycle the inductor current flow direction won't change, but the voltage across it will reverse therefore the inductor will be reset)*.

Now, there are few disadvantages of measuring the peak current from NMOS's source:

- Most importantly, the peak of the charging current cannot be detected because PMOS should be turned off once the peak is reached. By measuring the voltage at the PMOS-inductor junction and time-delta will give an idea but it's difficult to implement this at hardware level. So the inductor's saturation may not be prevented. This is **useful** especially when the **output is shorted**: The control loop will force the PMOS stay on indefinitely to increase the output voltage, so the inductor current can ramp up to infinity if not interrupted. This will eventually lead to core saturation. High-side measurement will bring an inherent protection for this. It's impossible to detect this with low-side measurement.
- Since there's going to be some time from turning off the PMOS to turning on the NMOS *(as stated before, NMOS doesn't have to be turned on but let's assume for a moment that it's going to be)*, the measured peak current won't be the actual peak current because the inductor will start to discharge. So the real peak current info will be lost (slightly).
- Although the voltage developed across the sense resistor will be ground-referenced which makes the measurement easier by eliminating the use of differential amplifier for the high-side measurement, the polarity will be reversed because the current will flow from source to drain. This brings a negative supply voltage requirement or an extra inverter.

Comment: "the peak of the charging current cannot be detected because PMOS should be turned off once the peak is reached." I don't quite understand this. In steady state the inductor current is a ramp signal. So would the peak of charing current is same as peak of discharing current so would you just measure the peak of discharging current and got the same result? I agree with the point that some time is needed to turn on NMOS. But even there is body diode, that diode is inside the NMOS it is same as current flowing the NMOS as we are measuing ID current, so would that cause any problem?

Comment: @hana If you are not measuring the current from the high side then the only thing you trust to turn the PMOS off is the feedback. If the feedback network is not well designed or if a failure happens this will eventually result in core saturation because nothing will stop the current rise. `just measure the peak of discharging current and got the same result?` when you turn the PMOS off with the help of feedback, it's not unusual to happen a ringing on the current waveform's peaks, especially in DCM, because of hard switching. This ringing will lead to false measurements. Although you can ...

Comment: ... put some time for the ringing to get dampen and then take the measurements, the measured value won't be equal to the peak because the discharging would already have started. It gets even worse if the ringing is serious and gets longer time. And this will lead to false measurements as well. Still, the measured values will be quite close but, if precision is a must, may not give a "close enough" result.

Comment: I agree with these problems due to low-side current sensing. I just edited my post. Can you comment on that as well?

Comment: @hana there's nothing wrong with your understanding. Yes, inductor current shape will be used in the PWM modulator. So, as long as you can catch the peak there's gonna be no problems. But low-side sensing would be noisy and requires more components, and high-side sensing is safer. One big concern is, as stated in my answer, the short circuit because PMOS will stay on during a short, so low-side current sensing will return zero therefore nothing will stop the inductor current rise which eventually results in saturation. Whatever method you choose, as long as you can catch the peak you're fine.

Comment: This is what Tim Williams said in the comment section above.  If I'm not mistaken, this means that low-side sensing to control is not possible. What do you think about this? ```I'm not sure where you think the low side current comes from. It's causational. There is no low-side current until the high side turns off! It can only ever be sensed once the state changes, but making the state change is exactly what you're sensing for in the first place. ```

Comment: @hana it's possible but it's not going to be real current-mode control. Although the ramp shape of the inductor current is used for the PWM modulator, you can still use an externally-generated ramp along with the inductor current shape *taken from previous cycle*. This is some sort of *faking* or *emulating* the peak current-mode control. There are chips that emulate peak current-mode control in this way.